# Placenote Swift - Wrong position after loading the same map

Tags: swift

I have used swift IOS for creating map and loading map. In creating function, I tried to add an object on the map and recorded its SCNVector3 location in Placenote database. After relaunching the app and loading the same map, I place the object on the recorded SCNVector3 location but the object is placed in another position.

The above problem only happens when I restart the app. Does anyone have the same problem? Thanks.

```
@IBAction func createMap(_ sender: Any) {
      LibPlacenote.instance.startSession()
      self.ptViz?.enablePointcloud()
      self.tapGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true

      // handleTap function added the object name & its SCNVector3 location
}

@IBAction func saveMap(_ sender: Any) {
      LibPlacenote.instance.saveMap(
            savedCb: { (mapID: String?) -> Void in
                  LibPlacenote.instance.stopSession()
                  self.ptViz?.clearPointCloud()
                  self.tapGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false

                  let metadata = LibPlacenote.MapMetadataSettable()
                  metadata.name = "test"

                  // self.userdata included all the object location
                  metadata.userdata = self.userdata
                        
                  if (!LibPlacenote.instance.setMetadata(mapId: mapID!, metadata: metadata, metadataSavedCb: {(success: Bool) -> Void in})) {
                       print ("Failed to set map metadata")
                  }
}

// Loaded Map
func onLocalized() {
      for item in self.objectList {
            let x = Float(item["userData"]!["x"]!)!
            let y = Float(item["userData"]!["y"]!)!
            let z = Float(item["userData"]!["z"]!)!

            let location = item["userData"]!["location"]!
            let position = SCNVector3(x: x, y: y, z: z)

            self.addLocation(location: location, position: position)
        }
}
```

Placenote database: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuXuB.png)

Comment: you will need to show some code before anyone can help - have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you don't need to show ALL of the code - but you will need to show how you create and load the map, and how you have stored and retrieved the position details

Comment: Sorry, I have already updated. If it is not clear enough, feel free to ask. Thanks a lot.